# Resize pdf object to the parent div size

Tags: html, css, angularjs, html-object

I render .pdf and .png file on a web page.

```
<table class="table">
  ...
    <tr ng-if=collapseimg >
      <td colspan="100%">
        <div ng-if="report._source.attachment && report._source.attachment.charAt(0) === 'i'">
          <object data="data:image/png;base64,{{ report._source.attachment }}"></object>
        </div>
        <div ng-if="report._source.attachment && report._source.attachment.charAt(0) !== 'i'">
          <object data="data:application/pdf;base64,{{ report._source.attachment }}"></object>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Where `report._source.attachment` is a base64 encoded string, for example, pdf string starts `JVBERi0x...` and png string - `iVBORw0KGgo...`.

My style (less) rules:

```
  object {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  embed {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

Image (png) resized correctly. But the style above doesn't produce any effect on pdf.

How to resize pdf to fit the parent div size?

Here is [a simulation in plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/mBo2OLs79i0b16m7q3gS?p=preview). What I need is pdf and png of the same size without hardcoding `width` and `height`.

Comment: Have a look here: https://plnkr.co/edit/mLznZau1FK4FLM6Vg1Qd?p=preview

Comment: @DincaAdrian nice, that's exactly what I want. Put it into an answer and I'll accept it.